Is there a convention to cite/refer to specific trademarks
We often find disclaimers stating that Foo-Bar is a registered trademark of Some Company LLC. For the mere purpose of stating that Foo-Bar is a registered trademark most probably sufficient.
But, is there a way to refer to the specific trademark, similar as one can refer to a specific patent?
With patents, one may state This product is protected by patents, but one can also state This product is protected by patents XXX, YYY and ZZZ., with XXX, YYY and ZZZ being the specific patent numbers.
Over on tex.se, I have posted a question on How to cite an actual trademark, however the underlying question of Is there a convention to cite trademarks? is better suited for this site.

united-states
Overview

is there a way to refer to the specific trademark, similar as one can
refer to a specific patent? . . .
Is there a convention to cite trademarks?

The correct way to cite to a particular trademark is context specific. Slightly different conventions apply in different contexts.
Also, often, particular courts or particular publications have their own specific style guides which are not universal.
This answer sets forth some of the main citation conventions and also provides general context for trademarks and protections similar to trademarks (for which there are rarely formal style conventions).
In legal scholarship and court filings
The Journal of the Patent and Trademark Office Society presents the following citation form for trademarks registered with the U.S. Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO):

GOLDEN OREO, U.S. Trademark Registration No. 2961410 (issued June 7,
2005).

It also suggests the following two possible citation forms for applications to register a trademark that are pending at the USPTO:

U.S. Trademark Application Serial No. 77/341,910 (filed Dec. 1, 2007).
U.S. TM App. No. 77/341,910 (filed Dec. 1, 2007).

The Trademark Reporter, which is a legal journal published by the International Trademark Association, has the following style rules for trademarks

Proper Reference to Trademarks
Except when uppercase or lowercase letters are part of the design,
generally distinguish trademarks from surrounding text by referring to
them in ALL CAPS.
The Kellogg Company recently launched a new KELLOGG’S EGGO waffle.
Last week, ToroHead, Inc. applied to register the trademark ToroMR.
A trademark should be used as a modifier, not a noun, and should be
followed by the noun it modifies.
a HERSHEY’S KISSES candy [not a HERSHEY’S KISS]
Never modify a trademark by pluralizing it.
TIC TAC candies [not TIC TACs or TIC TACS] KLEENEX tissues [not
KLEENEXES]
Trademarks should not be used as verbs:
Please XEROX the report. [incorrect]
Please use the XEROX copier to make six copies. [correct]
Trademarks should not be used in the possessive form unless the
trademark itself is possessive (e.g., JACK DANIEL’S whiskey). Do not
modify a trademark from its possessive form if the trademark is
possessive.
FEBREZE’s fresh scent [incorrect]
the FEBREZE spray’s fresh scent [correct]
JACK DANIEL’S whiskey [correct]
JACK DANIELS whiskey [incorrect]
JACK DANIEL’s whiskey [incorrect]
LEVI’S jeans [correct]
LEVI’s jeans [incorrect]

The Trademark Reporter, generally speaking, uses the "Bluebook" style standards for citations, which is the predominant standard for academic legal writing in the United States. The "Bluebook" also suggests styles for use in court documents that are somewhat less fussy and less demanding in terms of typefaces, but different courts in the U.S. differ in their preferred citation style.
Another style guide, which the The Trademark Reporter draws upon for one specific elaboration of the Bluebook style that it ordinarily utilizes is the Chicago Manual of Style. The Trademark Reporter adopts the following rule from that style manual.

Chicago Manual of Style Rule 8.152 states:
Although the symbols ® and ™ (for registered and unregistered
trademarks, respectively) often accompany trademark names on product
packaging and in promotional material, there is no legal requirement
to use these symbols, and they should be omitted whenever possible.
(If one of these symbols must be used at the end of a product name, it
should appear before any period, comma, or other mark of punctuation.)

If the status of a trademark is disputed or ambiguous, and is not claimed as a mark belonging to the author, it is sufficient to simply set it off using quotation marks or another distinctive typeface, as illustrated in the following image from a U.S. Supreme Court brief filed in a trademark case (an image rather than character depiction of this brief is used to preserve subtle typesetting details):

If the typesetting capacity of the publication or paper writing author's typing tool will not support the circle r registered trademark symbol, when explaining how a trademark was written on, for example, packaging, in legal writing, it is acceptable to use (R) instead of ®. See, e.g., the court opinion in Zatarain's, Inc. v. Oak Grove Smoke House, Inc., 698 F.2d 786 (5th Cir. 1983), which also illustrates a description of particular trademarks or claimed trademarks in a setting where the exact legal status of the trademark is disputed:

At issue is the alleged infringement  of two trademarks, "Fish-Fri"
and "Chick-Fri," held by appellant Zatarain's, Inc. ("Zatarain's").
The district court held that the alleged infringers had a "fair use"
defense to any asserted infringement of the term "Fish-Fri" and that
the registration of the term "Chick-Fri" should be cancelled. We
affirm. . . .
Zatarain's "Fish-Fri" consists of 100% corn flour and is used to fry
fish and other seafood. "Fish-Fri" is packaged in rectangular
cardboard boxes containing twelve or twenty-four ounces of coating
mix. The legend "Wonderful FISH-FRI (R)" is displayed prominently on
the front panel, along with the block Z used to identify all
Zatarain's products. The term "Fish-Fri" has been used by Zatarain's
or its predecessor since 1950 and has been registered as a trademark
since 1962.
Zatarain's "Chick-Fri" is a seasoned corn flour batter mix used for
frying chicken and other foods. The "Chick-Fri" package, which is very
similar to that used for "Fish-Fri," is a rectangular cardboard
container labelled "Wonderful CHICK-FRI." Zatarain's began to use the
term "Chick-Fri" in 1968 and registered the term as a trademark in
1976.
Zatarain's products are not alone in the marketplace. At least four
other companies market coatings for fried foods that are denominated
"fish fry" or "chicken fry." Two of these competing companies are the
appellees here, and therein hangs this fish tale.
Appellee Oak Grove Smokehouse, Inc. ("Oak Grove") began marketing a
"fish fry" and a "chicken fry" in March 1979. Both products are
packaged in clear glassine packets that contain a quantity of coating
mix sufficient to fry enough food for one meal. The packets are
labelled with Oak Grove's name and emblem, along with the words "FISH
FRY" OR "CHICKEN FRY." Oak Grove's "FISH FRY" has a corn flour base
seasoned with various spices; Oak Grove's "CHICKEN FRY" is a seasoned
coating with a wheat flour base.
Appellee Visko's Fish Fry, Inc. ("Visko's") entered the batter mix
market in March 1980 with its "fish fry." Visko's product is packed in
a cylindrical eighteen-ounce container with a resealable plastic lid.
The words "Visko's FISH FRY" appear on the label along with a
photograph of a platter of fried fish.

When two or more registered trademarks are very similar to each other (e.g., with the same words in different fonts or colors or with or without a stylized script) are being discussed in the same document or article, it is common to follow the practice in court documents and academic legal journals for patents in the same circumstances, by referring to the trademarks as, for example, "the '4910 mark", using an apostrophe followed by the last four numbers of the trademark registration number to refer to a particular mark, after a full citation for that registered trademark is used the first time it is referred to in the document or article.
In publications directed at the general public
U.S. trademark law establishes particular safe harbor ways of noting that something is trademarked in communications to the general public by someone claiming or acknowledging the validity of the mark.
When used in print, for example, on packaging or in marketing or other materials directed at the general public, where the trademark claim of someone other than the author is acknowledged or the trademark is claimed, there are different ways that different kinds of marks are acknowledged or claimed.
Different Kinds Of Trademarks And Service Marks
There is a hierarchy of different kinds of marks in U.S. law.
At the top of the hierarchy is a registered trademark issued by the U.S. Patent and Trademark Office on its principal register under the Lanham Act (which is the main federal trademark law). Registered trademarks carry with them a presumption that they are valid, that the registered owner is the owner of the trademark, that the trademark has a national geographic scope, and that the trademark has a national geographic extent with a date of first use established as presumptively valid as shown in the issued registered trademark. So, in a trademark infringement lawsuit, all of the prima facie case of the trademark owner except the facts related to the allegedly infringing party's use of the mark is established simply by referencing the trademark filing number before any evidence is presented (although these presumptions can be overcome with evidence presented at trial in some cases).
After a period of time, if the proper filings with the USPTO is made, most of the facts that are merely presumed for an ordinary registered trademark owner become "incontestable" and these presumptions cannot be overcome with evidence presented by a defendant accused of infringing the mark in a trademark infringement case, so all evidence in the infringement case relates to the alleged infringing acts of the defendant.
Certain incontestable registered trademarks can be established to be "famous marks" which are entitled to additional protections not available to ordinary incontestable registered trademarks.
In addition to matters of proof, the Lanham Act also provides remedies to registered trademark holders (such as the ability to have a court order that infringing goods that are imported be seized by customs officials at the border, and the ability to secure additional damages and criminal penalties), that are not available for any other kind of trademark or service mark.
All other trademarks that are lower on the trademark hierarchy than registered trademarks are denoted with the same safe harbor notation showing that the trademark is claimed or that the trademark of someone other than the author is acknowledged as valid. But, in the case of these trademarks, there is a distinction made between trademarks, in the narrow sense, which refer to goods, and service marks, which refer to anything other than goods.
Below registered trademarks in the trademark hierarchy are:

U.S.P.T.O. filed trademark claims that do not appear on the principal register. This filing puts the public on notice to a trademark claim that has national geographic scope, and provides proof of a date that the claim was made that is a matter of public record.

Trademark filings made with a state government, typically, with the Secretary of State of the relevant state government. This filing puts the public on notice to a trademark claim that has statewide geographic scope, and provides proof of a date that the claim was made that is a matter of public record.

Common law trademarks. These are not filed with any government agency. Their effective date is the date it is first used in commerce, and their geographic scope extends to the places where it is actually used.


Non-principal register USPTO filed trademarks, and state filed trademarks, are basically common law trademarks for which a public record exists to show a claimed date of first use and a presumptive valid claim to the geographic scope of the area where the mark was used. But, in all of these cases the burden of proving the validity of the trademark, the actual date of its first use in commerce, and where it is not presumed due to a public record filing the geographic scope of the trademark, is upon the person claiming to own the trademark or service mark on a case by case basis in an infringement lawsuit.
Acknowledged or claimed registered trademarks
When a registered trademark is used in print directed to the general public, one writes:

GOLDEN OREO®

Unlike patents, a reference to the registration number of a registered trademark is not conventionally included when a registered trademark is used in materials intended to be read by members of the general public (basically, because this would detract artistically from the use of the registered trademark in packaging and promotional materials).
Acknowledged or claimed trademarks that are not registered
Comment to this subsection: I don't know how to display a superscript in the Stack Exchange interface but would welcome an edit to do so.
Not all trademarks, however, are registered trademarks. If a trademark arises at common law from actual use in a particular market, or from a state law filing, then when the trademark is used in print, one writes as follows when one recognizes the validity of a trademark or service mark claim, or is making a claim to trademark or service mark status:
GOLDEN OREO™
or
GOLDEN OREO SM
with the letters TM  (trademark) or SM (service mark) as the case may be in superscript and no space between the letters TM or SM and the final character of the mark
The use of a superscript TM or SM is also the correct designation for a trademark or service mark which is on file with the U.S.P.T.O., but not on its principal register of registered trademarks (which essentially establishes a common law trademark that is presumed geographic extent of the entire United States).
Associated Press citation style

AP citation style does not use trademark or copyright symbols in our
text.  A trademark is a brand, symbol, word, etc., protected by law to
prevent a competitor from using it. In general, use a generic
equivalent unless the trademark name is essential to the story. When a trademark is used, capitalize it.

This source for the AP style also italicizes in addition to capitalizing the trademark in an example that it presents:

AstroTurf, for a type of artificial grass.

(Source citing the AP stylebook).
American Psychological Association citation style
Another common citation style in which trademarks are referred to is the APA style, which does not require the use of ® (i.e. a circle r for a registered trademark), or TM, or SM (for marks that are not Lanham Act registered trademarks), but does require that it be written in some form of distinctive typesetting. Specifically:

Always distinguish a trademark from surrounding text by:

Using it in all capital letters (or initial capitalization) (example – CANON cameras or Canon cameras);
Using it in a bold, italic, or underlined font (example – Canon cameras, Canon cameras, Canon cameras);
Placing it within quotation marks (example – “Canon cameras”);
Or using a stylized, graphic form (example – Canon cameras).

Be sure to use spacing, hyphenation, capitalization, etc. consistently
throughout your manuscript (example – NESCAFÉ coffee, not NES CAFÉ
coffee).
Use a trademark as an adjective to modify a noun, rather than using a
trademark as a noun or verb.
Correct: You skate while using ROLLERBLADE in-line skates.
Incorrect: You are rollerblading.
Additionally, the generic noun that identifies the product or service
should be used immediately after the trademark (example – Scotch brand
transparent tape).
Be careful not to modify a trademark by making it plural (example –
OREO cookies rather than OREOs).
Do not use a trademark in the possessive form unless the trademark is
inherently possessive (example – JACK DANIEL’S whiskey rather than
JACK DANIELS whiskey).

Legal rights that are trademark adjacent
Trademarks v. Trade names
A trademark is a "brand" under which a particular set of goods is sold, and a service mark is a "brand" under which a particular set of non-goods is sold, although the term "trademark" is often used in a broad sense that is inclusive of service marks as well.
A trademark or service mark is distinct from a "trade name" which is the proper name of a firm (although sometimes the word "trade name" is used in a narrow sense to refer to a name other than the proper name of a the firm under which a firm does business also called a d/b/a. for "doing business as" name, a term also used colloquially to refer to sole proprietorships that due business under a trade name but are not organized as a partnership, corporation, limited liability company, or other formally organized and registered business that is a legal person).
For example, "General Motors" is the trade name of a corporation, while "Chevy" is a trademark of General Motors referring to one of the brands under which General Motors and its authorized dealers sell a particular "make" of car, and "Silverado" would be on of many trademarks that refer to a "model" of vehicle sold under the Chevy trademark.
Trade names are cited like other proper nouns.
Statutory trademarks and geographic marketing protections
There are other terms in addition to trade names that are "trademark adjacent". These usually have individual statutes of their own that protect rights to use them, rather than utilizing the general law of trademarks.
Some of basically just statutory trademarks, like those of the Olympics. Most of these date to the era before there was a generalized federal statute protecting trademarks, or when it was only in the early days of being widely used. The Lanham Act, which was the first truly comprehensive and general federal trademark law was only enacted in 1946. Before that, all trademark protections except special statutory trademarks, were governed solely by the common law of case decisions originating from the common law case law related to unfair competition means, fraud, and defamation.
Other trademark adjacent protections, which are more common outside the U.S. (e.g., in Europe and Japan) than in the U.S., are regional designations for goods, usually agricultural or food and drink related, that meet the requirements for regional origins that allow the regional designation to be used.
The most famous example of this kind of trademark adjacent protection is "Champagne" for sparkling wine made in a particular region of France and meeting certain standards established by the French government.
"Kobe beef" for beef made from cows in a specific geographic region of Japan to certain standards established by the Japanese government  is another example.
Some of the main geographic designation protections in the U.S. are the words "Bourbon" to a geographically designated kind of whiskey with links to Kentucky that meets certain standards, and "Napa Valley" for certain wines made in a certain vineyard region of the U.S. state of California.
The U.S. often refuses to honor foreign geographical identifiers in the case of goods made in the style of a product with a geographical designator that is protected in foreign countries, in part, out of First Amendment free speech concerns and also due to non-legal customary English language usage conventions that support this non-recognition.
Statutory trademarks and geographic regional designations are stylistically cited like common law trademarks, but without a TM or SM designation.
Most private sector certifications are trademarks
Certifications of quality by third-parties, such as Underwriter's Laboratories (UL), are, however, genuine ordinary registered trademarks in U.S. law that indicate licensed permission to use the trademark from the entity that owns that trademark.

europe
Different authorities (national or international) will each have their own systems for identifying a specific registered trade mark. For example, in the recent UK case Match v Muzmatch [2023] EWCA Civ 454, we can see at paragraph 4 that the claimant was concerned about certain of their marks identified by numbers:

The Trade Marks are as follows:
i) EU Trade Mark No. 182253 MATCH.COM registered as of 1 April 1996 in respect of "information and consultancy services in the nature and field of on-line dating and introduction services" in Class 42.
ii) EU Trade Mark No. 16246639 MATCH.COM registered as of 13 January 2017 in respect of inter alia "downloadable software in the nature of a mobile application for internet-based dating and introduction" in Class 9, "providing a website featuring technology in the field of social media, namely, a website that enables users to send status updates to subscribers of web feeds, upload and download electronic files to share with others" in Class 42 and "dating services; internet based social networking, introduction and dating services" in Class 45.
iii) UK Trade Mark No. 3097217 shown below registered as of 3 March 2015 in respect of inter alia "providing social introduction and date-arranging services" and "dating agency services; matchmaking services; computer dating services; provision of dating agency services via the Internet" in Class 45.

The UK and EU marks are both given here by their numbers, but we also have to say what the registration authority was in order for that number to make sense.
UK numbers can be given more completely in a form like "UK00003097217" which is what the Intellectual Property Office will use. Some number ranges are used for special purposes. You will also see people omitting the leading "0" digits. But other countries or international organizations will do their own thing.
Again in the UK, these get published in the Trade Marks Journal, so one could also cite the issue number and date within which the entry appears. This can be found by using the database search and looking under "Publications". The journal has been in operation since 1876 and the first trade mark was numbered "1". (For historical citation purposes, the institutional publisher of the journal has changed from time to time, but it is still the same periodical.) The full registration data will include the mark itself, the claimed scope of its usage, and who has registered it.
Expressing these data in any specific citation system (Chicago, MLA, etc.) is a separate issue. The patent references you have already found in the linked question are probably a decent enough model for how to go about it.
